# Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 7 project, which is running correctly on My local. I build using ng build --prod and after that, I try to run project in Apache server. That is giving me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined
```

Comment: set `sourceMap` to `true` in your production build config in your `angular.json` and take a closer look at the error. Most of this errors come from not correct import statements or not correctly shared modules

Comment: @Zooly , I have try this but not working in my case